# how to deal with multiple 404 error pages in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I have a website pages folder with his module and admin folder with his module also.

In App routing module, i will import these two routes modules

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule) },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) },
]
```

And admin Router module

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PortailComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'admin',
            component: AdminComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'login',
                component: DashboardLoginComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'documents',
                component: FilesComponent
              },
              {
                path: '**',
                component: 404Component,
              },
            ]
          }
        }
   ]
```

And Page Router Module like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'home',
                component: HomeComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'contact',
                component: ContactComponent,
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                component: Admin404Component,
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I set each route in the admin so that the route that matches the admin uses the 404 component page of the admin and each route in the pages that do not match the pages for the 404 page? When I use '**' in both the admin and the pages for each 404, it shows me the 404 error of the pages when I visit the admin pages

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can redirect to your own custom not found route like this

```
 {
            path: 'notfound',
            component: User404Component,
 }
```

And use the below code for the global not-found route

```
{
            path: '**',
            component: Admin404Component,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the bottom of your routes array:

```
  {
path: '**',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full',
```

},